# How to Calculate Speed Of moving Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

**Problem**
I have a simple program that extract the interested ROI that will detect continues movement of an object (getting x,y coordinates ) at every frames.So I want to calculate speed of object in km/hour

**What I Have Tried**

1. Extract The Object
2. get the x and y coordinate at every frames

Can any one give me solution or steps to find-out speed into km/Hour

**Note:I found this Video on YouTube But Don't know how they are Calculating https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZHdZG3LNhE**
[image: Like This Example]

Comment: Note that if you want accurate measurement of speed, you will need to calculate the distance of the object from the camera, because if two objects are moving with the same speed across the camera's field of vision, an object that is closer will cross the screen more quickly.

Comment: Ok What is The Procedure after getting me distance of the object from the camera,

Comment: if you know your camera and the object, you can use the solvePnP function to get the object pose information in 3D space. If you know the time between two frames and the position at both frames, you can compute the speed of the object between those two frames.

Answer (score 1):

As J. Taylor in the comment mentioned, it depends on how far an object is from the camera. So first you need to know, for example, 1 meter in the current scene (from point `A` to point `B`) equals to 100 pixels in the image of the scene, then if an object moved 100 pixels, then it means the object moved for 1m. Then you will be able to calculate the speed of the object movement in the scene.

**Update:** You need to track the blob and get its center point and then calculate the distance of the current center point with the previous one and check how many pixels the object was moved, for example in every 100px=1m.

Hope it helped and gives you some idea!